# Can not submit with Remote Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

My remote validation is working, but when I submit the form the cursor focus on the valid field, and no error message.

This my code:

ProjectModel:

```
    [Required]
    [Remote("ProjectNameVerify", "Projects")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

ProjectsController:

```
    public ActionResult ProjectNameVerify(string name)
    {
       // ... 
        return Json("msg", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Project.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", Autofocus = "false" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `ProjectNameVerify` controller to this. False, then error message shown, true then you can submit the form.

```
public JsonResult ProjectNameVerify(string name)
{
   // ... 
    return Json({true/false}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Reference: [Remote Validation In MVC 5 Using Remote Attribute](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/remote-validation-in-mvc-5-using-remote-attribute)

Comment: is it not allowed to return string?

Comment: @ChingWang for remote validation you need to return boolean so that the validation can determine if it's already ok to submit or not. If what you're trying to achieve is to return an error message, you need to put your error message on Remote attribute it has a property there to set error message.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice for me:

ProjectModel:

```
[Required]
[Remote("ProjectNameVerify", "Projects")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

ProjectsController:

```
    public JsonResult ProjectNameVerify(string name)
    {
        if (Verify() == false)
        {
            return Json("errormsg", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```